# How to export all data from Elastic Search Index to file in JSON format with _id field specified?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, elasticsearch

I'm new to both Spark and Scala. I'm trying to read all data from a particular index in Elastic Search into a RDD and use this data to write to Mongo DB.

I'm loading the Elastic search data to a esJsonRDD and when I try to print the RDD contents, it is in the following format,

```
(1765770532{"FirstName":ABC,"LastName":"DEF",Zipcode":"36905","City":"PortAdam","StateCode":"AR"})
```

**Expected format,**

```
{_id:"1765770532","FirstName":ABC,"LastName":"DEF",Zipcode":"36905","City":"PortAdam","StateCode":"AR"}
```

How can I achieve the output from elastic search to be formatted this way?.

Any help would be appreciated.

The data retrieved from elastic search is in the following format,

```
(1765770532{"FirstName":ABC,"LastName":"DEF",Zipcode":"36905","City":"PortAdam","StateCode":"AR"})
```

**Expected format is,**

{_id:"1765770532","FirstName":ABC,"LastName":"DEF",Zipcode":"36905","City":"PortAdam","StateCode":"AR"}

```
    object readFromES {

    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("readFromES")
        .set("es.nodes", Config.ES_NODES)
        .set("es.nodes.wan.only", Config.ES_NODES_WAN_ONLY)
        .set("es.net.http.auth.user", Config.ES_NET_HTTP_AUTH_USER)
        .set("es.net.http.auth.pass", Config.ES_NET_HTTP_AUTH_PASS)
        .set("es.net.ssl", Config.ES_NET_SSL)
        .set("es.output.json","true")

        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val RDD =  EsSpark.esJsonRDD(sc, "userdata/user")
        //RDD.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(args(0))
        RDD.take(5).foreach(println)
        }
       }
```

I would like the RDD output to be written to a file in the following JSON Format(one line per doc),

```
{_id:"1765770532","FirstName":ABC,"LastName":"DEF",Zipcode":"36905","City":"PortAdam","StateCode":"AR"}
{_id:"1765770533","FirstName":DEF,"LastName":"DEF",Zipcode":"35525","City":"PortWinchestor","StateCode":"AI"}
```

Comment: what version of spark are you using ?

Comment: Spark version 2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"_id"` is a part of metadata, to access it you should add `.config("es.read.metadata", true)` to config.

Then you can access it two ways, You can use

```
val RDD =  EsSpark.esJsonRDD(sc, "userdata/user")
```

and manually add the `_id` field in json

Or easier way is to read as a dataframe

```
val df = spark.read
  .format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")
  .load("userdata/user")
  .withColumn("_id", $"_metadata".getItem("_id"))
  .drop("_metadata")
```

//Write as json in file

```
df.write.json("output folder ")
```

Here the spark is the spark session created as

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("Test")
  .config("spark.es.nodes","host")
  .config("spark.es.port","ports")
  .config("spark.es.nodes.wan.only","true")
  .config("es.read.metadata", true) //for enabling metadata
  .getOrCreate()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need some more clarification in the following aspects, 1. Say, I want to filter data based on ES query while reading from the index, how can I do that in the dataframe way?.  Does DF supports something like this,  val RDD =  EsSpark.esJsonRDD(sc, "UserData/user",myQuery)                                                 2. Say, I want to convert this data frame into a JSONRDD and then use it to push it to Mongo DB, how can I achieve that?. Thanks in advance

Comment: For 1, you can add a query `.option("query", myQuery)` and use  .option("pushdown", "true") in config. 2 you can directly a dataframe to mongo collection with `mongo-spark-connector`

Comment: If above answer helped please mark as answer and close it, you have asked couple of other question, move these question to another question

Comment: Sure I'll do that. I'm facing the following error, while trying with the approach that you have mentioned above, value $ is not a member of StringContext.withColumn("_id", $"_metadata".getItem("_id"))

Comment: you need to import `import spark.implicits._` or you can use `col("_metadata")` instead of `$"_metadata"`